# User Account Control Keeps Popping Up

Tags: windows-8.1, uac, windows-domain

I am signed into my laptop on a domain network.

I keep having a User Account Control login pop up asking me if I want to allow `Networks`to make changes to this computer.

This keeps popping up all of the time, but I seem to always notice it after my computer goes to sleep. It even kept doing it while the computer was asleep in my bag, which would wake up the screen and eventually drained my battery while I was on the road.

It asks me to sign in as the administrator, which I do, but it doesn't seem to remember my credentials.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling UAC?

Comment: Maybe something with your profile, Are you a domain admin? you can try adding yourself manually to the local admins group (Using another account) and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Do you have your MS account linked to your Domain account by any chance? What kind of network are you attached to (WiFi or wired)?

Comment: I am not logged in as the domain admin, though I have the admin username and password. I do not believe my MS account is linked, I think it's just recognizing that my MS account has admin privileges and can be used to make admin changes.

Comment: I added my domain account to the administrators group we'll see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Update:Even after adding my account to the admin group it is still doing it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else is still looking for the solution.
This microsoft hotfix resolved the issue:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3005346

Answer (score 1):

the UAC is set to warn you about any changes to windows. You can reduce the alert level as shown below to avoid such. Really important changes would be shown only [image]

Comment: I don't think modifying UAC levels is the best approach here. The fundamental question is WHY this is happening and treat the root cause, not how to cover it up and make the problem not bother you anymore.